# Variable is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I made a "login screen" that when you enter a name you will be transfer to another html file. I made a welcome back screen that says Welcome back, "username". But for some reason the variable that I use to take the value of the username field is undefined.
This is the login screen html code:

```
<form id="login-form" metod="post" action="main.html">
      <div class="txt_field">
          <input id="username" type="text" required>

          <label>username</label>
      </div>
      <input onclick="validate()" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
```

-> this is the js file:

```
let username1;
function validate(){
   username1=document.getElementById(username).value;
}
document.getElementById('show_username').innerHTML = username1;
```

-this is the after login html file

```
<center>
    <h1>Welcome back,<br>
      <span id="show_username"></span>
  </h1>
  </center>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
```

**ofc I didn't include all the code for basic reasons.

Comment: Initialize let username1 inside validate() function.

Comment: If I understand, once you submit the login form you are loading a new page. The JavaScript variables are reset as a new page is loaded. Normally the username should be given by the server since it is stored in the session (typically in PHP or the server-side technology). I would avoid doing that with JavaScript since it's not made for that. But you could store the username inside a cookie and read it later with some JavaScript. But as I said before, print the username on the server side when you are building the HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happens in JavaScript when you load your page:

```js
// username1  is set to null
let username1;
// validate() function is created
function validate(){
   username1=document.getElementById(username).value;
}
// show_username element is populated with username1 (still null)
document.getElementById('show_username').innerHTML = username1;
```

When you call the validate function, `username1` is updated but `document.getElementById('show_username')` is not.

You also are referencing a `username` variable instead of `'username'` as a string.

Your code will work if you move line 5 into the `validate` function, and fix that issue.

```js
let username1;
function validate(){
   username1=document.getElementById('username').value;
   document.getElementById('show_username').innerHTML = username1;
}
```

Comment: Do we also need to Initialize "let username1;" inside validate() function as well?

Comment: Maybe it's just me misunderstanding but he seems to have two different html files (login form and "logged" form). This, ofc, won't work despite fixing logic. Some sort of persistence is necessary (cookies, localStorage, whatever).

Comment: I made the changes as you said,  but now there is not even displaying undefined.